# Running remote X11 applications with unity menu and look and feel

Tags: unity, server, appmenu, remote-x-session

How do I configure a server (12.10 - 13.10) to run remote X applications using the Unity menu and look and feel?

I can run applications fine by logging into the server from my desktop, like so:

`# ssh -Y <servername>`

`# gedit`

But the application doesn't run with the same look-and-feel as the rest of the applications on the screen.

All suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Unity provides very limited ability to export it's desktop environment to remote machines.  CDE, it is not.

Instead, try using Unity Remote Desktop (VNC by any other name).  This is the 'Ubuntu approved' way to get the full Unity desktop running on your remote X server.  You will have the 'look and feel' because you are, in fact, actually using your Unity desktop for all your apps via (the VNC X client running on) your local X server.